# NSManagedObjectContext is not saving the NSManagedObject Values in SWIFT 3.0 and XCOde 8

Tags: swift3

I am facing a problem while saving the `NSManagedObject` to `NSManagedObjectContext` in Swift 3.0 and Xcode 8. Adding the code snippets for better Understanding

```
let config = NSManagedObject(entity: entityDescription!, insertInto: self.moc) as! Config
```

Here Config class is derived from `NSManagedObject`

```
class Config: NSManagedObject {

    // Insert code here to add functionality to your managed object subclass

}
```

Assigning the Key and value to my config as below and calling a save

```
config.key = "access_token"

config.value = access_token


            do
            {
                try config.managedObjectContext?.save()

            }catch let error as NSError
            {
                NSLog(error.localizedDescription)
                onCompletion("Login Failed")
                return
            }
```

This doesnt throw any error to me, but while fetching the value of access_token from NSManagedObject, value is nil

```
   do
    {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Config")

        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "key == %@", "access_token")

        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

        let fetchResults = try moc.fetch(fetchRequest) as? [Config]

        if(fetchResults?.count > 0)
        {
            //NSLog((fetchResults?.first!.value)!)
            return fetchResults?.first!.value

        }


    } catch let error as NSError{
        NSLog(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

What is wrong with this piece of code?

EDIT: I can see the following code where persistentStoreCoordinator is set for managedObjectContext

```
lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    return managedObjectContext
}()
```

Comment: This entirely depends on the managedObjectContext, if it is not associated with the persitentStoreCoordinator. The managedObjectContext should have persistentStoreCoordinator property set.

Comment: @Sachin - I can see this property set for managedobjectcontext, i have posted the same for more clarity, what else is missing ?

Comment: Can anyone please help me out on this ? I am not getting what is going wrong with this piece of code ?